# Why does "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" not refer the variable name or column?

Tags: c#, exception, nullreferenceexception

If you have multiple variables on one line it's always a guess which one might be the null.

Sometimes I split one inline statement over two statements on purpose so I can easier understand what variable it's talking about if an exception occurs.

But I assume that the compiler can anyway decide to merge these lines into one 'thing'? So why can it then differentiate between the variables, but not if it's in one statement?

I assume there is a really good reason, but to understand compilers and the underlying workings better; why can't it tell me which variable (or column) is causing the nullref exception?

```
// NullRefException pointing to this line
if ( GetSomeItemFromX().AmountOfLolCats > GetSomeItemFromY().AmountOfLolCats )
    return "yay";
```

vs

```
// now I can see which method is causing problems   
int amountX = GetSomeItemFromX().AmountOfLolCats;
int amountY = GetSomeItemFromY().AmountOfLolCats;

if ( amountX > amountY )
    return "yay";
```

A typical ASP.NET exception; which one is `null`?

[image]

I hope someone can teach us about the underlyings of compilers and a better understanding of things happening under the hood and the tradeoffs that are being made on that level.

Comment: It will be a very expensive operation for the Common Language Runtime to lookup the name of the variable / property that is causing the issue.

Comment: Apart from this I can´t see how your image relates to your code. Anyway in order to see debug-information you need the pdb-fle for your assembly.

Comment: I'm not sure about C#, but usually when a program is compiled, information like variable names is thrown away. C# stores the variable names in a .PDB file for use with a debugger.

Comment: @HimBromBeere; can you figure out from the image which of the two variables is pointing to null? The whole callstack doesn't say anything more, and all the debugging data is loaded.

Comment: Required reading: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/25#issuecomment-332675052, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/03/31/using-the-new-exception-helper-in-visual-studio-15-preview/ and https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2371587-better-nullpointerexception-error-message.

Comment: @DirkBoer You have three candidates for null on that line. ;)

Comment: @Silvermind argh true ;)

Comment: _It will be a very expensive operation for the Common Language Runtime to lookup the name of the variable / property that is causing the issue._ Um, when we crash, time is not an issue.